# Getting elements from Java Collection by using multiple inputs at same time

Tags: java

we have a list of contacts (name & phone number), by using the java collections i need to get the object from collection by passing name or phone number. Means, if we pass the name, we should get the record & if we pass the phone number, we should get the same record from that collection.

Could some one else help me out. ?

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: And then: put up the code you wrote so far. We are not doing your (home)work for you.

Comment: Hint: iterate and check or use maps.

Comment: @GhostCat , thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome. But just for the record: that link by Robin starts with "To the OP, their question seems pretty good." ... but your question doesn't even meet the criteria following that. You dumped requirements; without showing any evidence that you tried solving your problem yourself. And that rarely works here.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code by your one and here is some hints:

- write a class having property `name` and `number`.
- Take input and search it with custom `comparator`